# Should I delete my answer (after the question was edited)?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Why does God encourage humans to beat other humans?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/31309/3331) was edited to make it more appropriate for Stack Exchange. However, the edit effectively made both existing answers no longer answers to the question since they do not reference "prominent theologians and/or apologists". (My answer references a statement by Jesus, certainly a prominent theologian, on the existence of divorce in the law and extends/applies this exegesis to beating one's slave; however, Jesus did not directly address the law's permission of beating one's slave.)

Since my answer has received three upvotes (most of which were probably received before the edit and "I like this" voting might be more common on Christianity), deleting it would earn the Disciplined badge.

In any case, I intend to wait before taking action; the original poster may revert the edit and edit the question into one more appropriate for Stack Exchange without invalidating my answer.

Comment: I would wait a few days to see, then delete or edit.

Comment: Can your answer be edited to match the new question without changing the basic sentiment by citing references?

Comment: Another thing to consider is not answering Truth questions in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a question shouldn't be altered in a way that makes the existing answers no longer fit unless it is an alteration by the original poster specifically because those answers didn't address his question or because the question would otherwise not fit the site (and thus the answers don't fit either unless you have some alternate way in mind to make it so that it still fits the answer and lets the question fit the site.)

In the case where the OP modifies the question, it is best that you delete your answer as it doesn't actually address what the OP was trying to ask.  If you feel it is of value to the site, you can post your own form of the question that you were answering and post your answer with it.

If the question was modified because it can not fit the site and your answer doesn't fit the site either, then it should be deleted as a poor fit.  If the argument is that your answer was answering a "Truth" question, then yes, you should probably delete it if that is the case.

If the question was modified to unnecessarily make the answer not fit, then the edit to the question itself is poor and should be altered or possibly reverted as there is a disagreement over the meaning of the question that only the OP can really answer.

In this particular case, it sounds like the middle option is the one that probably applies.

Comment: Since I made the edit, I'll just say that in my opinion, it ***was*** the middle option. The question wasn't a fit as it was, and could only have been salvaged by editing.  Most of the answers were of a "Truthy" nature.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that the question should have been closed, rather than edited in the first place.  The editor (who is a mod here, too), tried to narrow the question to fit site guidelines, but IMO, that did more harm than good since there were already answers.

A better solution would have been to close the question as **Too Broad**, and let the existing answers stand.  Later, the OP, or someone else, could have asked the more specific question if they so desired.

Comment: In retrospect, I agree. I think I was trying to be helpful to a newcomer, but maybe being consistent on what gets closed would be more helpful.